# How to divide a list to allocate it to another dataframe based on sum of values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes for example:

First dataframe contains the name and kind of chocolate they want:

| Name | Chocolate |
| --- | --- |
| Kirti | Nutella |
| Rahul | Lindt |
| Sam | Lindt |
| Joy | Lindt |
| Mrinal | Kit Kat |
| Sai | Lindt |

The second dataframe contains shop and availability of each item in shop:

| Shop | Chocolate | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Shop 1 | Lindt | 2 |
| Shop 2 | Lindt | 3 |
| Shop 1 | Nutella | 5 |

The end result that I'm looking for should return a dataframe which indicates which shop the people can go to.

Rahul, Sam, Joy and Sai are 4 people who want Lindt. 2 of them can go to Shop 1 and other 2 can go to shop 3 to ensure everyone can get lindt Chocolate.

Now we can randomly assign 2 of them to shop 1 and 2 of them to Shop 2.
Similarly with other chocolates and resulting dataframe will be

| Name | Chocolate | Shop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Kirti | Nutella | Shop 1 |
| Rahul | Lindt | Shop 1 |
| Sam | Lindt | Shop 1 |
| Joy | Lindt | Shop 2 |
| Mrinal | Kit Kat | NA |
| Sai | Lindt | Shop 2 |

In above case, Mrinal doesn't get assigned any shop because no shop has KitKat available

I've been trying to do a vlookup in Python using map but all people who want Lindt get assigned Shop 2. I want to assign them in such a way that divides the qty available in each shop so that everyone possible can get chocolate.

Here's the code that I wrote as of now:

```
df_demand = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Kirti','Rahul','Sam','Joy','Mrinal','Sai'],
                          'Chocolate': ['Nutella','Lindt','Lindt','Lindt','Kit-Kat','Lindt']})


df_inventory = pd.DataFrame({'Shop':['Shop1','Shop2','Shop1'], 
                             'Chocolate':['Lindt','Lindt','Nutella'], 
                             'Count':[2,3,5]})

df_inventory = df_inventory.sort_values(by = ['Count'], ascending = False, kind = "mergesort")
df_inventory= df_inventory.drop_duplicates(subset ="Chocolate")

df_inv1= df_inventory.set_index('Chocolate').to_dict()['Shop']
df_demand['Shop'] = df_demand['Chocolate'].map(df_inv1)
```

Output of above code:

[image]

Comment: @Timus I have added the code in the question above

Comment: If you have not enough chocolate on all shop, what should be the result?

Comment: @Corralien In above example, if lindt qty available in stores was only 3 and 4 people want the lindt chocolate, then any one random person should be assigned 'NA'

Comment: Do you need to balance on all shops? On you example, 3 people could be set to shop2 and only one person to shop1. Is it possible or people should be well balanced? It's important to know for the algorithm

Comment: No, balance is not needed. 
I want to assign maximum people to the shop with the highest quantity first.

So, if Shop1 has 3 lindt, and shop2 has 2 lindt, and 4 people want lindt. Then 3 people should be assigned to shop 1 and 1 person should be assigned to shop2

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is to count Chocolate need/sale opportunity up and then use that number to merge the request of the kids with the corresponding shops.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['Shop1','Lindt',1],
     ['Shop1','Milka',1],
     ['Shop2','Lindt',3],
     ['Shop3','Lindt',3],
     ['Shop3','Milka',3]]
    ,columns=['Shop','Chocolate','Count'])

dk = pd.DataFrame(
    [['Alfred','Milka'],
     ['Berta','Milka'],
     ['Charlie','Milka'],
     ['Darius','Milka'],
     ['Emil','Milka'],
     ['George','Lindt'],
     ['Francois','Milka']],
    columns =['Name','Chocolate'])

df['max_satisfaction']=df.groupby('Chocolate').cumsum()
df['min_satisfaction'] = df['max_satisfaction']-df['Count']
df['satisfies']=df.apply(lambda x:list(range(x[-1],x[-2])),axis=1)
df = df.explode('satisfies')
dk['request_number'] = dk.groupby('Chocolate').cumcount()
dk = dk.merge(df,how='left',
          left_on=['Chocolate','request_number'],
          right_on=['Chocolate','satisfies'])

dk[['Name','Chocolate','Shop']]
```

Note that this solution will be quite expensive if the shops have way more supply than demand. A limit to prevent the explosion of `df` could be however easily implemented.